# DLE рейтинг пользователей

Tags: dle

Как в DLE происходит подсчет рейтинга пользователя, и в какой таблице/поле находятся эти значения?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме

Answer (score 1):

В functions.php функция **ShowRating** смотри там